# Excel: Combining multiple cells into a single cell via lookup referencing two separate columns as criteria

Tags: excel, concatenation, aggregate, multiple-conditions

In efforts to create a dynamic tracking sheet for Purchase Orders, I have stumbled into an issue. Often times, we have a single Purchase Order that is broken out into multiple containers and shipped by our suppliers. We are having to tracking these to ensure that all product is shipping by the requested ship date. At times, this sheet can become lengthy in excess of 1,500 lines or more. Therefore, I am trying to create a form that would be a "one stop shop" for tracking all needed information. From our SAGE 500 database I am able to pull via criteria using SQL an "Open PO" report that shows me all Purchase Order Lines that have a quantity open to receive greater than 0. We then are needing to use excel's functionality to populated the remaining data that is being hand keyed into a spreadsheet.

We receive packing lists from our suppliers via PDF format. These are going to be manually entered into a spreadsheet and then referenced into this master PO tracking sheet. I am needing to use look up functions to grab the amounts that have shipped and the container they are on. I have been able to use a `SUMIFS` formula to aggregate together the total amounts that have shipped by using both Purchase Order Number and Item Number as the two criteria and place in the 8th column. However, I am not able to successfully create a method to grab the two unique container numbers that the shipments are on and place them in a single cell separated by a ", ". As you can [see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4oME.jpg), I need to return what I have in the cell with "TCNU123456, HIMU123456" by searching through column D. The result needs to be a concatenate separated by a comma and a space. I need to only return the container number if both Purchase Order Number and Item Number match exactly which makes is a multiple criteria `vlookup`. Does anyone have any ideas of how this can be done?

I really appreciate any feedback or assistance!

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems have you run into? This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will attempt to edit my original post to make it more clear. I am far from seasoned at writing code or advanced functions. I am just having an issue at work that has stumped me and knew that others might have had a similar situation and were able to develop a solution.

Comment: If you have one of the Office 365 solutions, you can use `TEXTJOIN` operating on an array generated by `IF` to concatenate the desired results. Earlier versions of Excel will require extensive use of helper columns.  You might be able to minimize, but not eliminate, the number if your data is sorted.  Or you could use VBA.  Again, please read Help for the topics I mentioned in my earlier comment.